# How to restrict code access in module federation?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I want to use micro frontend for one of my client project at work. The requirement of project is such that we will be using horizontal split and at some places might use vertical split. Since client wants team autonomy, he wants to restrict code access to that particular module. Below is the diagram for my UI architechture. Since everything will be in its separate repo, how will people who are working on modules will be able to check their micro frontend with the host app while developing?

For example: Host - team A, MFE-1 - team B, MFE-2 - team C, MFE-3 - team D

Each of them have separate repos and cannot access other code base of other modules. So how will "MFE-1", "MFE-2" and "MFE-3" will be able to decide how UI developed by them will be integrated in "Host". Also what can be done to enhance development experience so that each module developer can see how much part of the screen they will be utilizing or to test how the micro-frontend will look after integrating with the host app locally without accessing the "Host" code base.

[image: UI architechture]